# Choose statistical test method: comparing the frequency of a disease (only interested the disease post-procedure) in 2 groups of patients

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, odds-ratio, likelihood-ratio, clinical-trials

I am working on 2 groups of patients, group A and group B. The patients in both groups have received a same procedure. We have observed the patients before and after the procedure.
Suppose there is a disease (Ds), some of the patients have this disease before the procedure, some of them have developed this disease after the procedure, and others don't have this disease during the observation.

I want to do a statistical test to see if the post-procedure disease frequency in group A and group B are different.

What will be the best statistical test to process? Which set of data shall I work with? (# of patients with Ds post-procedure/# of patients without Ds) or (# of patients with Ds post-procedure/# Total patients in each group)

| Group | # of patients with Ds post-procedure | # of patients without Ds | # Total patients in each group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 179 | 485 | 1398 |
| Group B | 801 | 3933 | 8362 |

*the patients with Ds pre-procedure are not listed in the table since we are only interest the patients with Ds post-procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the total number of patients. In order to compare both groups, you only need to take into account the number of patients without the disease before and after. Then it becomes a very common statistical analysis performed via t-test

Comment: Could you explain how you conduct a t-test when all you have are two counts?

Comment: @whuber: I'm confused: the table indicates that Group A has 1398 patients, and Group B has 8362 patients. How is that "two counts"? Even with down-sampling to only those with Ds post-procedure, it looks to be a sufficient sample for the $t$-test to me.

Comment: @Adrian This answer appears to claim, explicitly, that only two counts are needed.  I'm trying to understand how to interpret that.

Comment: @whuber: Well, I would read this answer as follows: You only need to take into account the counts of patients without the disease before the procedure, and the counts of patients without the disease after the procedure. Both counts would, I take it, be in the hundreds, no? Or am I making a category mistake?

Comment: @Adrian The reason I asked for clarification is that it seems the answer can be understood in multiple ways: that is, it's ambiguous.  I can't respond to your comment because I truly don't know for sure what this answer is trying to say.